# Condor quoting hell

Tags: python, condor

I'm having trouble with passing a string representation of a dict to be read in by `json.loads` in Python through Condor.

On the command line I would type:

```
python script.py arg1 "{'x':50,'y':'a'}"
```

After much struggle with the docs, I understand Condor wants in the submit file:

```
arguments = "arg1 '""{''x'':50,''y'':''a''}""'"
```

However it is failing and claiming quadruple single quotes around the dict strings in the log, eg:

```
''''x'''':50
```

Is there any way to manipulate the quotes to get it to run as expected?

Comment: Have you tried using triple quotes? It's not exactly PEP8, but in your case it could work. `"""'Single' or "double" quotes in here won't ""interfere"" with the ''string'' literal."""`

Comment: @ZacCrites No, `json.loads` doesn't like that.

Comment: You enclose the string literal in triple quotes. `json.loads` should not even be aware of how the string is represented syntactically.